# Symfony 6 my login form does not connect me no error message

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony6

I have a problem with my login form, I can't connect, I have no error message, it just doesn't connect me.

To do a test I recreated a blank symfony project (6.1.*).
I created the registration and the connection with the following lines:

php bin/console make:user

php bin/console make:auth

php bin/console make:registration

The registration works perfectly the problem really comes from the login, I came across a lot of posts that talk about the support() function but nothing worked.

EDIT :
The problem only occurs on my server hosted by O2Switch.

With some tests I saw that the request goes through the function :

- Security/AppCustomAuthenticator:authenticate
  Security/AppCustomAuthenticator:onAuthenticationSuccess

but not in

- Authenticator/FormLoginAuthenticator:getLoginUrl
  Authenticator/FormLoginAuthenticator:supports
  Authenticator/FormLoginAuthenticator:authenticate

EDIT 2:
My problem is similar with to [Symfony 4 login form : authenticating successfully, but authentication immediately lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902619/symfony-4-login-form-authenticating-successfully-but-authentication-immediate)

my files:

Security/AppCustomAuthenticator.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_home'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

SecurityController :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Entity/User :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account with this email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private $isVerified = false;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Security.yaml :

```html
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Log :

```html
[2022-08-12T13:53:04.932322+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"0043df"},"request_uri":"https://manga-racoon.com/_wdt/0043df","method":"GET"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.869373+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\LoginController::index"},"request_uri":"https://manga-racoon.com/login","method":"POST"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.880959+00:00] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main","token_class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Token\\UsernamePasswordToken"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.930854+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Connecting with parameters array{"url":"<redacted>","driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"lvng4771_racoon","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.3.32","charset":"utf8mb4"} {"params":{"url":"<redacted>","driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"lvng4771_racoon","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.3.32","charset":"utf8mb4"}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.936027+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? (parameters: array{"1":2}, types: array{"1":1}) {"sql":"SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ?","params":{"1":2},"types":{"1":1}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.941639+00:00] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"provider":"Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider","username":"mail@gmail.com"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.941729+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.941775+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:27.944990+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 (parameters: array{"1":"mail@gmail.com"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1","params":{"1":"mail@gmail.com"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.563502+00:00] security.INFO: Authenticator successful! {"token":{"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Token\\UsernamePasswordToken":"UsernamePasswordToken(user=\"mail@gmail.com\", roles=\"ROLE_USER\")"},"authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.567180+00:00] security.DEBUG: The "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\FormLoginAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called {"authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.580275+00:00] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.586138+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.586509+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?   AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT TABLE_NAME\nFROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?\n  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'\nORDER BY TABLE_NAME","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.587142+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.587352+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?   AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT TABLE_NAME\nFROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?\n  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'\nORDER BY TABLE_NAME","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.591074+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.591375+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement:     SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,            t.ENGINE,            t.AUTO_INCREMENT,            t.TABLE_COMMENT,            t.CREATE_OPTIONS,            t.TABLE_COLLATION,            ccsa.CHARACTER_SET_NAME       FROM information_schema.TABLES t         INNER JOIN information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY ccsa             ON ccsa.COLLATION_NAME = t.TABLE_COLLATION WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_NAME = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"    SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,\n           t.ENGINE,\n           t.AUTO_INCREMENT,\n           t.TABLE_COMMENT,\n           t.CREATE_OPTIONS,\n           t.TABLE_COLLATION,\n           ccsa.CHARACTER_SET_NAME\n      FROM information_schema.TABLES t\n        INNER JOIN information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY ccsa\n            ON ccsa.COLLATION_NAME = t.TABLE_COLLATION WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_NAME = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.592449+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.592687+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT DISTINCT            k.CONSTRAINT_NAME,             k.COLUMN_NAME,             k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,             k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,             k.ORDINAL_POSITION /*!50116,             c.UPDATE_RULE,             c.DELETE_RULE */ FROM information_schema.key_column_usage k /*!50116 INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints c ON c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME AND c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA */ WHERE k.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND k.TABLE_NAME = ? AND k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY k.ORDINAL_POSITION (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT DISTINCT            k.CONSTRAINT_NAME,\n            k.COLUMN_NAME,\n            k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,\n            k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,\n            k.ORDINAL_POSITION /*!50116,\n            c.UPDATE_RULE,\n            c.DELETE_RULE */\nFROM information_schema.key_column_usage k /*!50116\nINNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints c\nON c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME\nAND c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME\nAND c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA */ WHERE k.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND k.TABLE_NAME = ? AND k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY k.ORDINAL_POSITION","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.603236+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT       COLUMN_NAME        AS field,        COLUMN_TYPE        AS type,        IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,        COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,        COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,        EXTRA,        COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,        CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,        COLLATION_NAME     AS collation FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT       COLUMN_NAME        AS field,\n       COLUMN_TYPE        AS type,\n       IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,\n       COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,\n       COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,\n       EXTRA,\n       COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,\n       CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,\n       COLLATION_NAME     AS collation\nFROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.604943+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.605203+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT        NON_UNIQUE  AS Non_Unique,         INDEX_NAME  AS Key_name,         COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name,         SUB_PART    AS Sub_Part,         INDEX_TYPE  AS Index_Type FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT        NON_UNIQUE  AS Non_Unique,\n        INDEX_NAME  AS Key_name,\n        COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name,\n        SUB_PART    AS Sub_Part,\n        INDEX_TYPE  AS Index_Type\nFROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.607478+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions {"sql":"SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.609510+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.622684+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.754960+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\LoginController::index"},"request_uri":"https://manga-racoon.com/login","method":"GET"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.762418+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.762499+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.762555+00:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.840218+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Connecting with parameters array{"url":"<redacted>","driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"lvng4771_racoon","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.3.32","charset":"utf8mb4"} {"params":{"url":"<redacted>","driver":"pdo_mysql","host":"127.0.0.1","port":3306,"user":"lvng4771_racoon","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":{"collation":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"},"dbname":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","serverVersion":"mariadb-10.3.32","charset":"utf8mb4"}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.845939+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.848401+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?   AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT TABLE_NAME\nFROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?\n  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'\nORDER BY TABLE_NAME","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.849535+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.849777+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?   AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"}, types: array{"1":2}) {"sql":"SELECT TABLE_NAME\nFROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?\n  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'\nORDER BY TABLE_NAME","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2"},"types":{"1":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.857783+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.858104+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement:     SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,            t.ENGINE,            t.AUTO_INCREMENT,            t.TABLE_COMMENT,            t.CREATE_OPTIONS,            t.TABLE_COLLATION,            ccsa.CHARACTER_SET_NAME       FROM information_schema.TABLES t         INNER JOIN information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY ccsa             ON ccsa.COLLATION_NAME = t.TABLE_COLLATION WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_NAME = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"    SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,\n           t.ENGINE,\n           t.AUTO_INCREMENT,\n           t.TABLE_COMMENT,\n           t.CREATE_OPTIONS,\n           t.TABLE_COLLATION,\n           ccsa.CHARACTER_SET_NAME\n      FROM information_schema.TABLES t\n        INNER JOIN information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY ccsa\n            ON ccsa.COLLATION_NAME = t.TABLE_COLLATION WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_NAME = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.859158+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.859383+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT DISTINCT            k.CONSTRAINT_NAME,             k.COLUMN_NAME,             k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,             k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,             k.ORDINAL_POSITION /*!50116,             c.UPDATE_RULE,             c.DELETE_RULE */ FROM information_schema.key_column_usage k /*!50116 INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints c ON c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME AND c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA */ WHERE k.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND k.TABLE_NAME = ? AND k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY k.ORDINAL_POSITION (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT DISTINCT            k.CONSTRAINT_NAME,\n            k.COLUMN_NAME,\n            k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,\n            k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,\n            k.ORDINAL_POSITION /*!50116,\n            c.UPDATE_RULE,\n            c.DELETE_RULE */\nFROM information_schema.key_column_usage k /*!50116\nINNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints c\nON c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME\nAND c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME\nAND c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA */ WHERE k.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND k.TABLE_NAME = ? AND k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY k.ORDINAL_POSITION","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.869527+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT       COLUMN_NAME        AS field,        COLUMN_TYPE        AS type,        IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,        COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,        COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,        EXTRA,        COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,        CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,        COLLATION_NAME     AS collation FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT       COLUMN_NAME        AS field,\n       COLUMN_TYPE        AS type,\n       IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,\n       COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,\n       COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,\n       EXTRA,\n       COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,\n       CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,\n       COLLATION_NAME     AS collation\nFROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.871248+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.871576+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT        NON_UNIQUE  AS Non_Unique,         INDEX_NAME  AS Key_name,         COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name,         SUB_PART    AS Sub_Part,         INDEX_TYPE  AS Index_Type FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX (parameters: array{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT        NON_UNIQUE  AS Non_Unique,\n        INDEX_NAME  AS Key_name,\n        COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name,\n        SUB_PART    AS Sub_Part,\n        INDEX_TYPE  AS Index_Type\nFROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX","params":{"1":"lvng4771_Manga-racoonv2","2":"doctrine_migration_versions"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.873849+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions {"sql":"SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.875819+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT DATABASE() {"sql":"SELECT DATABASE()"} []
[2022-08-12T13:53:28.893231+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
[2022-08-12T13:53:29.188544+00:00] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"9da054"},"request_uri":"https://manga-racoon.com/_wdt/9da054","method":"GET"} []
```

EDIT :
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: `I came across a lot of posts that talk about the support() function but nothing worked.` So you verified [Authenticator::supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253287/symfony-5-4-securitybundle-cant-login-after-register/71270988#71270988) is working and that Authenticator::authenticate is being called?.

Comment: The supports() function is not called but the authenticate function works.

Comment: How do you test if it passes through the function?

Comment: In the authenticate function I dumped $email and it answers me well the email but in the supports() the dd("test") is not visible.

Comment: no i didn't change anything about the csrf, I tested on my own server with Symfony server:start and the connection works, my problem comes from my server hosted by O2Switch.  (Info on my project that doesn't work it goes through onAuthenticationSuccess() )

Comment: yeah i've already tested several configurations but none of them work yet it works a few months ago

Comment: When you talk about the Authenticator::supports function you are talking about the one in the FormLoginAuthenticator file or the one in AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator ?

Comment: I too looked on a lot of topics about what was written in the logs I added on my subject (Authenticator does not support the request);
When I try to login, only the breakpoint in the FormLoginAuthenticator : supports() function works. The breakpoint put in the abstract doesn't work. 
If you look at the error messages in logs, have you a hint on what is going on  ?

Comment: I edited my post with a screen of the supports() function

Comment: Okay.  It's clear we are not actually getting anywhere.  I committed my test code to a [repository](https://github.com/cerad/security61).  If you want you can clone it out and test under `symfony server:start` and your O2Switch server.  Resist the temptation to change anything except the database connection stuff.  If you still get calls to FormLoginAuthenticator::supports() under O2Switch using my unchanged code then that would be a real mystery.

Comment: I can't take it anymore, your project works locally but doesn't work on my server. but after testing I added a dd("test") in FormLoginAuthenticator::supports() and nothing is displayed on the server or in local.

Comment: The AppCustomAuthenticator::supports route is called

Comment: the function return false

AppCustomAuthenticator.php on line 29:
false

Comment: The false condition comes is $request->isMethod('POST')

self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route') return True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey we just found the response. In fact, the user get logged but log out instantly when the page refresh. We get a message: "Cannot refresh token because user has changed." .
If you happen to get the same issue, go to your User Entity and implemente the "EquatableInterface" with the method isEqualTo(), if worked for us.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        // if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
        //     return false;
        // }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->email !== $user->getEmail()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).